# containsKey method of TreeMap returns false despite that the key is already in the Map

Tags: java, treemap, containskey

I try to write a program that counts all the words in text file.
I put any word that matches the patterns in TreeMap.

The text file I get through `args0`

For example, the text file contains this text: `The Project Gutenberg EBook of The Complete Works of William Shakespeare`

The condition that checks if the TreeMap already has the word, return `false` for the second appearance of word `The`, but returns `true` the second appearance of word `of`.

I don't understand why...
This is my code:

```
public class WordCount
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
        // Locale locale = new Locale("en", "US");

        Path p0 = Paths.get(args[0]);
        Path p1 = Paths.get(args[1]);
        Path p2 = Paths.get(args[2]);

        Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]");
        Matcher matcher;
        Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("'.");

        Map<String, Integer> alphabetical = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();

        try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(p0))
        {
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                // System.out.println(line);
                for (String word : line.split("\\s"))
                {
                    boolean found = false;

                    matcher = pattern1.matcher(word);
                    while (matcher.find())
                    {
                        found = true;
                    }
                    if (found)
                    {
                        boolean check = alphabetical.containsKey(word.toLowerCase());
                        if (!alphabetical.containsKey(word.toLowerCase()))
                            alphabetical.put(word.toLowerCase(), 1);
                        else
                            alphabetical.put(word.toLowerCase(), alphabetical.get(word.toLowerCase()).intValue() + 1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        matcher = pattern2.matcher(word);
                        while (matcher.find())
                        {
                            found = true;
                        }
                        if (found)
                        {
                            if (!alphabetical.containsKey(word.substring(1, word.length())))
                                alphabetical.put(word.substring(1, word.length()).toLowerCase(), 1);
                            else
                                alphabetical.put(word.substring(1, word.length()).toLowerCase(), alphabetical.get(word).intValue() + 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `boolean check`, it's not used anywhere! BTW, I've just tried your code (but reading from file not using `args`) and it works fine.

Comment: I know that it's not used anywhere, I just use this variable in debug mode.

The `while (matcher.find())
      {
       found = true;
      }`
is to check if the word is full match to the pattern.

Any help?

Comment: You don't need the `while loop`, I tried your code and it's working as expected! It gives the expected output and the `boolean check` is working as expected as well!

Comment: if I use `String str = "The Project Gutenberg EBook of The Complete Works of William Shakespeare";`

so the `if (!alphabetical.containsKey(word.toLowerCase()))` returns `true` for the second  appearance of word **The** but if I use `String word : line.split("\\s")` I get `false`.

Why?

Comment: How do you know it returns `true`? the `check` code doesn't contain the negation operand!
Try to write `System.out.println(word + ": " + check);` exactly under the `check` line and tell me what is the result.

Comment: `?The: false
Project: false
Gutenberg: false
EBook: false
of: false
The: false`

This from the text file.
I don't know why I get `?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested your code, it is ok. I think you have to check your file encoding.

It is certainly in "UTF-8". Put it in "UTF-8 without BOM", and you'll be OK !

Edit : 
If you can't change the encoding, you can do it manually. See this link : 
http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-handle-utf8-file-with-bom.html

Regards

Comment: my file is `UTF-8`
How it's related?

Comment: You get a ? at the start of the file when reading it.It is the  byte order mark I think. Change its encoding for UTF-8 without BOM and it should be OK.

Comment: If I open the text file with `Notepad` I only see that the file is `UTF-8`, 
but when I open the file with `Notepad++` I see that my file is `UTF-8-BOM`

When I change it to `UTF-8` it's works.

But my input text file isn't for change because the person that will check my program don't want to make this changes.

How can I progress?

Comment: if I use : `newBufferedReader(Path, Charset)` and `Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8-BOM");` so I get : 
`Exception in thread "main" java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: UTF-8-BOM
 at java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Unknown Source)`


What I need to do?

Comment: You can see here how to handle the bom in java (you have to do it manually) : http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-handle-utf8-file-with-bom.html

Comment: Thanks a lot!!
I add this code before the `while` : `// BOM marker will only appear on the very beginning
   reader.mark(4);
   if ('\ufeff' != reader.read())
    reader.reset(); // not the BOM marker`
and now it's works well.